# How do you launch a URL in the default browser from within a winmobile application?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

In normal C# desktop apss, you can launch a URL by saying:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

but System.Diagnostics.Process on windows mobile doesn't seems have that string overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me in WindowsMobile:

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = url;
    myProcess.Start();
}
catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this blog has your solution

http://www.businessanyplace.net/?p=code#startapp

It uses the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) call

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8fz649y.aspx , and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx you should be able to do:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
Process.Start(psi);
```

However, I haven't tested this on CF.